# Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView In List Adapter

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to inflate

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp" />
```

in List adapter so that I can play video in the listview it self but I am getting error

**Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView**

while if I am using

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp" />
```

It is getting inflated without any error and I am able to display thumbnail in list view

My requirement is when user click on this thumbnail video should play in list view

Please suggest how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView):

> Using this View directly is an alternative to using the
>   `YouTubePlayerFragment`. If you choose to use this view directly, your
>   activity needs to extend `YouTubeBaseActivity`.

Therefore, you must make sure your activity extends `YouTubeBaseActivity`. Alternatively, if your activity does not need to extend an activity provided by the library, you can use the `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` and FrameActivity from android.support.v4.

```
<fragment
  android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
  android:id="@+id/youtubesupportfragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: But then the method is _setSupportActionBar(toolbar);_ gives an error as it can not be called if your activity is not extending from _AppCompatActivity_. What to do if the toolbar is necessary?

Comment: @not_a_bot My QuestionLink is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38694028/5059725 I have still Error inflating class fragment, with other error Binary XML file line #15: Duplicate id 0x7f1001d0, tag null, or parent id 0x7f1001cf with another fragment for com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

Answer (score 2):

In your java file `MainActivity.java` try to replace `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity` with  `public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to not_a_bot's answer, I'd like to add that you should make sure that you call `super.onCreate(Bundle)` method, as it seems that `YouTubeBaseActivity` class doesn't have the `@CallSuper` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use fragment in your layout, another solution that you can use is extends your activity from `YouTubeBaseActivity()` . This will allow you use `<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView/>` inside your layout

Example:

```
class PlayVideoActivity : YouTubeBaseActivity(), YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {...}
```