# Youtube Player View within Tab Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I simply use YoutubePlayer within one of my Tab Fragments, but couldn't integrate it!

With this code, it gives me this error.

```
Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
```

Here is my Fragment class.

```
public class Frag_Trailer extends Fragment {

    YouTubePlayerView mYouTubePlayerView;
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener mOnInitializatedListener;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trailer, container, false);
        mYouTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_youtube);
        mYouTubePlayerView.initialize(YouTubeConfig.getYoutubeApiKey(), mOnInitializatedListener);

        mOnInitializatedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo("_XgQA9Ab0Gw");
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            }
        };

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here are the dependencies that I have in `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies { 
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0' 
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0' 
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar') 
}
```

Comment: Please share your `build.gradle`.

Comment: Should I add something to build.gradle?
Here is it;

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}

Comment: Please modify the jar inclusion in the `build.gradle` like this and let me know if the problem persists. 
`implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Comment: Error still occurs. I think I made the class wrong.

Answer (score 0):

based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570169/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-youtube-player-youtubeplayerview-in-lis)

you have to extend your activity with `YouTubeBaseActivity`. But in your case, you implement it on your Fragment, so change your view XML like this

```
<fragment
  android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
  android:id="@+id/youtubesupportfragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```